# What does $(2n+2)!$ mean?

Tags: factorial

I don't understand why $(2n+2)!$ is equal to $(2n+2)(2n+1)(2n)!$ even though I think I understand what a factorial number is (7·6·5·4·3·2·1 = 7!). Any hints?

Comment: maybe it is (2(n+1))!

Comment: Sorry, my bad there was a typo. Edited the question. Thanks!

Comment: $$\begin{align}(2n+2)! &= 1\cdot 2\cdot\ldots\cdot (2n)(2n+1)(2n+2) \\&= \left[  1\cdot 2\ldots\cdot (2n) \right](2n+1)(2n+2) \\&= (2n)!(2n+1)(2n+2)\end{align}$$

Comment: $2n+2$ and $2n+1$ are the first two factors of $(2n+2)!$. Then $(2n)!$ are the remaining factors. Example with $n=2$ is as follows. $2n+2 = 6$, then $6! = 6\cdot 5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 = (6 \cdot 5) \cdot (4\cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1) = (6 \cdot 5) \cdot 4!$.

Comment: $(2n+2)! = \underbrace{1\cdot 2 \cdot ... \cdot n \cdot (n+1) \cdot ... \cdot (2n)}_{=(2n)!} \cdot (2n+1) \cdot (2n+2)$

Comment: Thank you guys – it's a lot more clear now! Feel free to post your comments as an answer and I'll be happy to +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an example of $n=3$, we have $2n+2=8, (2n+2)!=8!=8\cdot 7 \cdot 6!=(2n+2)(2n+1)(2n)!$  You are just sorting out the first two terms of the factorial.

Answer (score 1):

$(2n+2)!=(2n+2)(2n+1)(2n)(2n-1)(2n-2)...3·2·1$
$(2n)!=2n(2n-1)(2n-2)...3·2·1$

So $(2n+2)(2n+1)(2n)!=(2n+2)(2n+1)2n(2n-1)(2n-2)...3·2·1=(2n+2)!$

Answer (score 1):

$(2n+2)!=(2n+2)(2n+1)(2n)(2n-1)\cdots3\times 2\times 1=((2n+2)(2n+1))((2n)(2n-1)\cdots3\times 2\times 1)=(2n+2)(2n+1)(2n)!$